# Dynamic DataTemplates (pref. Silverlight)

Tags: wpf, silverlight, listbox, datatemplate

Is it possible to have a ListBox with a Data Template that changes depending on certain properties of the ItemsSource?  For instance maybe you want a list with a variety of items such as images, video, custom panels, etc.  Was hoping it could behave like some sort of factory.

Any ideas how this would work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WPF land you'd use a [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), which unfortunately doesn't exist in Silverlight, but there are several articles, like [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20200809115648/http://geekswithblogs.net/tkokke/archive/2009/09/28/datatemplateselector-in-silverlight.aspx), around showing how to put something similar together.